# Object Reference not set to an instance in ASP.Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webapi

In Manage.Data project I've Admin repository and I've implemented service calls in admin repository. I've a another project Manage.API and I've a class called Authenticate.cs. I want to call GetLoginInfo() method from Authenticate.cs class file.

```
private IManageRepository _memRepository;
_memRepository.GetLoginInfoAsync("","",Guid.Empty);
```

Its not working. Could anyone please guide me.

CustomAuthenticate.cs

```
namespace CamManager_API
{

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class CustomAuthorization : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private IManageRepository IManageRepository;

        public CustomAuthorization(IManageRepository manageRepository)
        {
            this._manageRepository = manageRepository;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This will Authorize User
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
           
            if (filterContext != null)
            {
                Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues authTokens;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authTokens);

                var _token = authTokens.FirstOrDefault();

                if (_token != null)
                {  
                    string authToken = _token;
                    if (authToken != null)
                    {
                        var responseModel =  _manageRepository.GetLoginInfoAsync("","",Guid.Empty);

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsValidToken(string authToken)
        {
            //validate Token here
            return true;
        }
    }
}


ManageRepository.cs

using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CamManager.DataAccess
{
    public class ManageRepository : SqlRepository<Member>, IManageRepository
    {
        public ManageRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

        public override async Task<Login> GetLoginInfoAsync(string firstName, string password, Guid accessKey)
        {
            using (var conn = GetOpenConnection())
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("@Firstname", firstName, System.Data.DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("@Password", password, System.Data.DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("@AccessKey", accessKey, System.Data.DbType.Guid);
                return await conn.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Login>("Login", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
        }
        public override async Task<IEnumerable<Member>> GetAllAsync()
        {
        }
        public override async Task<Member> FindAsync(long id)
        {
        }
        public override async Task<Result> InsertAsync(Member entity)
        {
        }
        public override async Task<Result> UpdateAsync(Member entity)
        {
        }
        public override async Task<Result> DeleteAsync(long id)
        {
            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Getting error "Object Reference not set to an instance"

Comment: And are you ever initializing `_memRepository`? It seems to me you will have a hard time with C#, I recommend you read a tutorial, you need to understand objects, interfaces, etc.

Comment: As others have mentioned, it is hard to see your implementation as there is not a lot of code here. Do you have a more complete example and/or the full error?

Comment: Hi All, I've implemented the below code. But haven't uploaded it.

Comment: private IManageRepository _manageRepository;
        public CustomAuthorization(IManageRepository manageRepository)
        {
            this._manageRepository = manageRepository;
        }

Comment: @Abhishek, like I commented in the answer, you REALLY need to share more of your code. You are just showing two lines and there's no way to help you this way. If you are not familiar with how to instantiate a class, then you have a bigger problem that you should solve FIRST. And if you are using a Dependency Injection Container, you are in an even more complex situation.

Comment: Hi All, I've edited the Question and added the files Please look at it.. thanks for the responses.

Comment: Hi All, Please find the update code

Answer (score 2):

maybe you need to init your repository  in the constructor... otherwise show us all file content to detect the exact problem

```
public class MainClass
{
    private IManageRepository _memRepository;
    public MainClass(IManageRepository _memRepository)
    {
        this._memRepository = _memRepository;
    }
}
```

Add this code to your startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddScoped<IManageRepository , ManageRepository >();
}
```

Comment: Hi Lajil... I've executed the above code. I am getting error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'manageRepository' of 'CustomAuthorization.CustomAuthorization(IManageRepository)'"

Comment: @Abhishek, you REALLY need to share more of your code. You are just showing two lines and there's no way to help you this way. If you are not familiar with how to instantiate a class, then you have a bigger problem that you should solve FIRST.

Comment: it will be more easy to help you if you share all the code

Comment: Hi Lajil A... i've edited my question and added the code. Please look at it and help me

Comment: @Abhishek - your "updates" show us nothing.  If the error occurs on the line with `_memRepository`, *THEN YOU FAILED TO INITIALIZE* "_memRepository"!  It's as simple as that.  Lajil Adel (correctly!) suggested you might use [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).  There are other altnernatives, too.  *BUT YOU NEED TO SHOW US THE CODE FOR*"_memRepository" (vs. "_manageRepository").  Who knows?  Maybe "_memRepository" is just a typo, and you really meant "_manageRepository"?

Comment: Hi @paulsm4 You can see the code for _manageRepository in the same code box. I've pasted it down. And in startup.cs, I've already written the code which you suggested.

Comment: 1) Q: Is the error occurring on the line with "_memRepository"?  *PLEASE SHOW US THE LINE of CODE THAT'S FAILING*!  Also show us the *CLASS*.  "Authenticate"?  That's important. 2) Q: Are you familiar with the debugger? If not, learn it.  Now.  Otherwise, set a breakpoint where you *THINK* you're initializing the variable.  3) Check the value at initialization.  Make sure you *ARE* initializing it.  I *THINK* you probably need to initialize "_memRepository" (*NOT* "_manageRepository"!) in class "Authenticate's" constructor. 5) Update your post with this information.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to register your Interface for the ASP dependency injection. Otherwise the DI cannot do anything. [More information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IManageRepository, ManageRepositoryImplementation>();
}
```

> Whereby **ManageRepositoryImplementation** is just a placeholder for
> the class which implements the interface IManageRepository and you want to create an instance of. This
> information only you can know.

Then do it like [Lajil Adel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11204244/lajil-adel) said:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private IManageRepository _memRepository;
    public MainClass(IManageRepository _memRepository)
    {
        this._memRepository = _memRepository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll separate your question in half, one is base your current approach and better suitable one.

I realize that the goal you trying to achieve is to build a custom authentication challenge, and working alone or combine with the default one.

With your current approach:
The attribute wont work like that (you should give it parameter less constructor or just some constant flag to mark something special), otherwise, you won't get native DI. The compiler will yelling at you like this

[Require constructor param right the moment you use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxlEc.png)

If you want to keep your approach for the sake of simplicity, you will have to register your service first.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IManageRepository, ManageRepository>();
}
```

You can register the service as singleton or scope depending on how you manually create your SqlConnection.

Then take the service out of the HttpContext like this:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        var manageRepository = filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetRequiredService<IManageRepository>();
    }
```

There you go... implement the rest of your logic.

A better approach:

Give [authentication scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) a shot, then build a policy scheme to apply corresponding scheme for each Action or may be the whole controller.

This give you a central place to describe your authentication/authorization process in the app it's much clearer and highly adoptable with complex authentication requirement.

Combine this with redis rather than sqlConnection would be much better and scalable for production environment.